# fixing the error: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a component - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I keep running in to the

> error: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a component.

I've looked at other solutions but not sure how to fix it. I've tried removing the space within text components as suggested and that doesn't work not sure what to do next.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Image,
    Text,
    ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';

const profileImage = require('./images/user-profile.jpg');
const friendsIcon = require('./images/profile.png');
const favIcon = require('./images/plain-heart.png');
const msgIcon = require('./images/chat.png');

class MainApp extends Component {
    state = {
        name: 'Crysfel',
        lastName: 'Villa Roman',
        occupation: 'Software Engineer',
        friends: '1,200',
        favorites: '2,491',
        comments: '4,832',
    };

    renderStat(options) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.stat}> 
          <Image
            source={options.icon} 
            style={[styles.icon, options.selected ? 
            styles.selected : null]} 
          /> 
          <Text style={styles.counter}>{options.value}</Text> 
        </View>
      );
    }


    render() {
      const {
          name,
          lastName,
          occupation,
          friends,
          favorites,
          comments,
      } = this.state;

      return (
        <ImageBackground source={profileImage} style={styles.container}> 
          <View style={styles.info}> 
            <View style={styles.personal}> 
              <Text style={styles.name}>{name} 
              {lastName} 
              </Text> 
              <Text style={styles.occupation}> 
                {occupation.toUpperCase()} 
              </Text> 
            </View> 
            <View style={styles.stats}> 
              {this.renderStat(
              {icon: friendsIcon,value: friends, selected: true })} 
              {this.renderStat({ icon: favIcon,value: favorites })} 
              {this.renderStat({ icon: msgIcon,value: comments })} 
            </View> 
          </View> 
        </ImageBackground>
      );
    }
}


export default MainApp;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        height: null,
        width: null,
    },
    info: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
        top: null,
    },
    info: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
        top: null,
    },
    personal: {
        padding: 30,
    },
    name: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    occupation: {
        color: '#d6ec1b',
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    selected: {
        tintColor: '#d6ec1b',
    },
    icon: {
        tintColor: '#504f9f',
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
    },
    counter: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 15,
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    stats: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    stat: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#7675b7',
        borderColor: '#6e6db1',
        borderLeftWidth: 1,
        flex: 1,
        padding: 10,
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is a expo link without icon assets it is running fine https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/laughing-strawberries

Comment: Looks like everything is fine in your code except container's height and width in styles.

Comment: `renderStat(options) {` make this to `renderStat = (options) => {` and see what happens

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ I used your suggestion and nothing changed